# OSX Server 10.9 File Sharing - not working properly

Tags: macos, sharing, user-account, server.app, file

I have a 10.9 server with file sharing enabled.  One of the users decided to change the permissions on the folder and was doing some "spring cleaning" now all of my shares are not visible from the workstations except one "Home Folders"  This is the only share that has staff(primary group) where as the others and new shares have "administrators (primary group)".  How can I change this as the users that are not administrators cannot see any other shares when browsing to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's the group ownerships, from the command line you could do:

```
chown -R yourusername:staff /Path/To/SharedFolder
```

for each of the shares, if the other non-admin users you mentioned are in the `staff` group. Otherwise, replace `staff` with the correct group. It's possible you may *not* want *all* the directories underneath the shared directory shared, so you'd have to go in and alter the permissions/ownership for each of them too, or remove the `-R` and change folders individually.

See some examples of `chown` [here](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/uchown.htm) and an explanation of the command I've given [here](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=chown+-R+yourusername%3Astaff+%2FPath%2FTo%2FSharedFolder).

I'd also note down what the current ownership and permissions are using `ls -l`, so that you can change them back if this doesn't work.

(obviously, replace `yourusername` with your username, and `/Path/To/SharedFolder` with the path to the shared folder. I say "obviously" but I'm writing this because, according to my experience, it's not always obvious!:)

Comment: I've followed your directions and have reset permissions to match on all the folders, now I'm still not seeing the folders when I browse to the server with any users except Administrators.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Now I'm almost convinced that it's the user accounts that are causing the issue.  When I create a new user they get denied to access the server, even though the test shares are wide open and the new user has full permissions.  thoughts?

Comment: The directories are definitely marked as shared? http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/apple-in-the-enterprise/apple-os-x-server-configure-file-sharing/ (I know it's a stupid question but then it's probably going to be one of those things where your colleague unticked a check box somewhere…)